# Communication from Daemon-to-Binary Applications Design for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, plugins, kernel-extension, daemons

I am Designing an application that requires a Command Line Application binary to use for remote/local usage.  The application will have plugins that will allow for addition and removal by the user.

1. Will NSDistributedNotificationCenter work for IPC(inter-process communication) between daemons and binary applications?  If not what alternatives do we have?
2. What direction for adding a plugin architecture to a daemon would be "Best Practice" in relation to future OSX Compatibility?
3. Since there might be a KEXT involved,  and the binary(CLI App) might be unsigned do we have to include a bundle for the CLI App to interoperate with the KEXT in the future?